# Sort by dd from dd/mm/yyyy in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Get the records when entered value dd matches in dd/mm/yyyy instead of entering dd/mm/yyyy

Example if I entered only dd = 12 from dd/mm/yyyy.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: can you elaborate further ?

Comment: `ORDER BY DAY(datecolumn)`

Comment: can you please give me example statement in ms sql

Comment: this is a bit confusing. The thread title said "SORT", the content looks like you want a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ?

```
WHERE DATEPART(DAY, datecolumn) = 12
```

Comment: it says Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: what is the data type of your datecolumn ? STRING ?

Comment: datecolumn is nvarchar(50)

Comment: then you probably had bad data in there. check your data

Comment: sir by nvarchar can we execute the above statment

Comment: if possible, you should use date or datetime data type for your date column